# VueJS model not updating when select2 input is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, jquery-select2

We are using Vue 0.12 for legacy reasons and I am trying to use the latest version of select2 to implement a tagging interface. I have select2 working fine, but the Vue model for my tag element is not being updated. I am very new to Vue (And advanced JS as a whole) so I apologize if this is a poor question. Here is the relevant portion of my JS:

```
ready: function(){
    var self = this;
    $("#tags").select2({
        tags: true
    });
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<select name="tags" id="tags" multiple v-model="client.tags">
<option value="test1" selected>Test1</option>
<option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

On the initial page load, `vm.client.tags` is equal to `["test1"]` as it should be. After adding a new tag to the input, though, `vm.client.tags` is still equal to `["test1"]` but `$('#tags').val()` is equal to `["test1", "test2"]` as I would expect. I think what is happening is that `select2` is not triggering some event that `Vue` needs in order to update the model, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html for an example of handling Select2 with Vue.

Comment: We are not using Vue 2 on this project so I don't think this example will work. Additionally, that example does not work with multiple values selected, which is what is needed for tags. When I modify that code using dev tools to implement the multiple select functionality, the demo ceases working.

Comment: Your comment did lead me to https://012.vuejs.org/examples/select2.html though which is the same example, for Vue 0.12. That definitely puts me closer. I still have the problem though in that it doesn't work for multiple selections like I need it to.

Comment: Possible to create a fiddle of it?